# "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I was trying to test my API in DJango, but while trying to use a POST request to create a user, the following error shows up:

```
"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."
```

What should I do? Can I remove this? Or how should I pass the CSRF also in testing and in production? In theory, I put the false in CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE, so, I don't know what to do.

Comment: django or django-rest?

Comment: Rest, I am making an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add CSRF token to the request(and postman):

```
data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token, "username": "thesamething", "email": "thesamething", "password": "thesamething" }
```